# How to make excel file to be downloadable

Tags: java, browser, download

I have generated excel report and i want the file to be downloaded by the user ,so how to set the response properties (content type) .

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to set the headers and content type like this:

```
    response.setHeader "Content-disposition", "attachment;filename=myExcel.xls"
    response.contentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
```

Then stream the content in the response.

Edit: If you need to set the content length:

```
    response.contentLength = 100
```

Content length documented in the [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#setContentLength%28int%29)

Comment: As user of the site, I'd like to use benefits of content-length header too.

Comment: I am getting gibberish as response when I am trying this. I am getting a downloadable file but in response I am getting gibberish which does not happen when I try the same process with a pdf file.

Answer (score 3):

```
response.setContentType("APPLICATION/OCTET-STREAM");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "Attachment;Filename=\"MyFile.xls\"");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have To Add [jxl jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/jxl/jxl.jar.zip)

and

Try this code :

```
@WebServlet("/Reportexel")
public class Reportexel extends HttpServlet
{
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        try
        {
            response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=kbdemo.xls");
            response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
            WritableWorkbook workbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(response.getOutputStream());    
            WritableSheet worksheet = workbook.createSheet("Sheet 1",0);

            Label lbl = new Label(1,1,"Hello");
            Label lbl1 = new Label(1,2,"Hi...");

            worksheet.addCell(lbl);
            worksheet.addCell(lbl1);

            workbook.write();
            workbook.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.err.println("Main Error : "+e);
        }
    }
}
```