# How to download .xls file with angularjs sent with readAllBytes

Tags: angularjs, download, restangular

I have in my backend application an spray route that pushes out a .xls file using

`FileUtils.readAllBytes(xlsFile)`

In my frontend application I'm using angularjs with Restangular module so I need to receive my .xls file and download it to user's computer.

I have in my code

```
Restangular.one("localhost:9090/excel")
        .get()
        .then(function(response){
            alert("Excel is here!");
            var hiddenElement = document.createElement('a');
            hiddenElement.href = 'data:attachment/xls,' + encodeURIComponent(response);
            hiddenElement.download = 'reporte-anual.xls';
            hiddenElement.click();
        });
```

but it only does the alert.

How can I achieve that?

Thank you all

Comment: You don't need to do all that, just [set the right headers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921923/how-to-make-excel-file-to-be-downloadable) on the server side

Comment: @JoseM From my backend I'm sending 3 headers ... 

Access-Control-Allow-Origin`(AllOrigins),
`Last-Modified`(DateTime(System.currentTimeMillis())),
`Content-Disposition`("attachment", Map(("filename", filename)))